# UPnP event subscription using blocking Socket on a Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, upnp

I am tyring to subsribe to an event on a UPnP device (the WeMo motion sensor). I first send an HTTP subscribe request to the device, and the device should start sending me event notification on the designated address. That part is working fine (except that I am getting too many notifications; even when the status is not changing, but it is a different problem for a different thread)

If I run the keepListening Function on a separate python process, everything is working fine . However, when I run the function as a thread, it doesn't work;

```
import socket
import requests
from threading import Thread

def keepListening(): #running this function on a separate process works
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.settimeout(600)
    sock.bind(('192.168.10.231',1234))
    sock.listen(5)

    while 1:
        notification = ''

    try:
        conn, addr =  sock.accept()
        conn.setblocking(1)
        notification= conn.recv(1024) 
        conn.sendall(r'''HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

''')
    except Exception as er:
        print er

    print notification




x = Thread(target=keepListening)
x.start()

message = {
'CALLBACK': '<http://192.168.10.231:1234>',
'NT': 'upnp:event',
'TIMEOUT': 'Second-600',
'HOST': '192.168.10.159:49153'}

k = requests.request('SUBSCRIBE','http://192.168.10.159:49153/upnp/event/basicevent1',headers=message)
print k
# keep doing other important works
```

Each event notification must be replied with a 200 OK reply, otherwise the device won't send further notification; a fact I learned the hard way. A doubt I have, which might be silly, is that, when running in a thread, as opposed to a separate process, the reply message doesn't get sent in timely manner, so the device doesn't send any more notifications.
It is worth mentioning that, even when I run the function in a Thread, I **do get** the initial notification after the subscription (Devices must mandatorily send an initial notification right after a subscription according to UPnP protocol), but I get no further notification (indicating that my 200 OK reply didn't get through properly; I do see it in wireshark though)

Any idea on what might be the difference in running the function in a thread (as opposed to a separate process) that makes it fail?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume, what is happening is that you end up sending your subscribe request before thread becomes active and starts listening on the interface. So the device can not connect to the socket.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to put time.sleep(2) after starting the thread, to give it some time to start, before sending the subscription request, but it doesn't help. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A few day ago I got a wemo motion sensor, switch and RaspberryPi, so I started tinkering.

The script subscribes to the „binaryState“-event of the wemo-device.
Every time the event occurs it prints out an „Alert“ (you can do other things there).
After 250 seconds it renews the subscription.

To adapt the script to your needs, you have to change the IPs:

localIp : your Computer

remoteIp: the ip of the wemo-sensor or switch

I’m new to python (started 3 days ago), so the script might need some revision, but it works.

```
import socket
import threading
import requests

host = ''
port = 1234
localIp = '<http://192.168.1.32:1234>' # local IP of your computer 
remoteIp = '192.168.1.47:49153' # the ip of the wemo device 

global uid # stores the uuid of the event
uid = ''

class client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        super(client, self).__init__()
        self.conn = conn
        self.data = ""

    def run(self):
        global uid
        while True:
            self.data = self.data + self.conn.recv(1024)

            if self.data.endswith(u"\r\n"):
                print self.data # data from the wemo device

                uidPos = self.data.find("uuid")
                if uidPos != -1: # data contains the uuid of the event 
                    uid = self.data[uidPos+5:uidPos+41]

                if "<BinaryState>1</BinaryState>" in self.data:
                    print "ALERT ------------------------------------------Alert"      
                    # NOTIFICATION ! 

                if "/e:propertyset" in self.data:
                    self.conn.sendall('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n')
                    return 
                self.data = ""

    def send_msg(self,msg):
        self.conn.send(msg)

    def close(self):
        self.conn.close()

class connectionThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        super(connectionThread, self).__init__()
        try:
            self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.s.bind((host,port))
            self.s.listen(5)

        except socket.error:
            print 'Failed to create socket'
            sys.exit()
        self.clients = []

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print uid
            conn, address = self.s.accept()
            c = client(conn) 
            c.start()
            print '[+] Client connected: {0}'.format(address[0])

def main():
    get_conns = connectionThread(host, port)
    get_conns.start()
    print get_conns.clients
    while True:
        try:
            response = raw_input() 
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit()

def setCalback():
  global uid
  threading.Timer(250.0, setCalback).start()
  if uid == "": # no uuid set so we subscribe to the event
    eventSubscribe()
  else:         # uuid is set, so we renew the subsciption
    eventRefresh()


def eventSubscribe(): # subscribe to the wemo-event 
    message = {
        'CALLBACK': localIp,
        'NT': 'upnp:event',
        'TIMEOUT': 'Second-300',
        'HOST': remoteIp} 
    k = requests.request('SUBSCRIBE', "http://"+remoteIp+'/upnp/event/basicevent1',headers=message)
    print k


def eventRefresh() # refresh the subscription with the known uuid
    myuid = "uuid:"+uid
    message = {
        'SID': myuid,
        'TIMEOUT': 'Second-300',
        'HOST': remoteIp } 
    k = requests.request('SUBSCRIBE',"http://"+remoteIp+'/upnp/event/basicevent1',headers=message)
    print k


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Timer(2.0, setCalback).start() # wait 2 sec. then subscribe to the service
    main()
```